# AG-Grid: How to enable custom sorting on client side in Server Side Row Model

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to figure out how to get custom sorting on the client side to work on a server-side row model. Also, what does a comparator do on an SSRM?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean performing the sort on the client side for a server-side row model, you can't, precisely because the data to be sorted is on the server, not the client.

If you just mean giving the user the ability to specify the sort order to the server so that the server can sort the data before returning, then that is built-in - the grid includes the sort in the parameters to the server.

You can read the documentation at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/server-side-model-sorting/#server-side-sorting

Comment: Hi I user sorting with server side, but still sorting not works !